# Heroku not installing requirements.txt contents in Ruby/Python app

Tags: python, ruby, heroku, pip, youtube-dl

This is a weird case. I am using Ruby/Sinatra to develop an API and I use pip/python only to install `youtube-dl`.

I created a new Heroku app with `heroku create` command and added `heroku/ruby` and `heroku/python` buildpacks.

My `/download` endpoint uses `youtube-dl` CLI. When I make a call to that endpoint, on my app's Heroku logs I can see a message saying "youtube-dl: not found".

I specified in my `requirements.txt` file to install `youtube-dl` and `ffmpeg`. The file looks like this:

```
youtube-dl
ffmpeg
```

When I try to download it manually by running `heroku run pip3 install -r requirements.txt` it says that `pip3` command can't be found. I tried `pip` instead of `pip3` as well.

I am not that experienced in Heroku so I don't know if this is even possible. What are my options here?

Comment: With PyPI you can only install Python packages. For ffmpeg you can install Python bindings but you cannot install ffmpeg. ffmpeg is a binary used for audio/video conversion, editing, ... . Setup a virtual development environment, get it running and then do `python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Those are the **Python** dependencies you need. You will need to install ffmpeg separately in another buildpack.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. When I run that command inside of Heroku bash I get this error: `/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `runtime.txt` file inside of my project. It contains my Python version:

```
python-3.8.2
```